# How do I type ® under mathpazo?

Tags: font-encodings, mathpazo

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

How do I type ® under mathpazo?

\end{document}
```

This piece of code interprets

[image]

I thought it was about encoding, so I make `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

How do I type ® under mathpazo?

\end{document}
```

I get nothing:

[image]

I would like to have the number, alphabet and equation under `mathpazo` but how do I type special character like ®? Do we have encoding other than `fontenc` and `inputenc`?

Comment: You have to use *both* `fontenc` and `inputenc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\textregistered`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
Test\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
Test\textregistered
\end{document}
```

Output example:

[image: textregistered]